# How can I send and receive emails from Joomla?

Tags: email, joomla

How can I send and receive emails from Joomla?

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 3):

Need to be more specific than that.

1. if you want to send emails to users registered on your website, you need to use somekind of newsletter component - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter
2. If you want to sent email programmatically, easiest way is to use
    
   `JUtility::sendMail($from, $fromname, $recipient, $subject, $body, $mode, $cc, $bcc, $attachment, $replyto, $replytoname);`
3. if you need it to be more advanced get mailer and configure on your own

   ```
   $mailer =& JFactory::getMailer();
   $mailer->IsHTML(false);
   $mailer->setSubject("Hello World");
   $mailer->setBody("Hello from Joomla");
   $mailer->addRecipient('your@email.com');
   $mailer->AddCustomHeader('X-Header: example');
   $mailer->Send();
   ```
4. If you want your users to email each other, you might want to use PMS (Private Messages System) http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/pms. I would recomment [UddeIM](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/pms/3206), great messaging system.